# Why my theme's css not working on another site

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, css

I work on my on theme based on Neve theme. First I had problem with scripts, because not working but i had to change their location from footer.php to header.php to everything was good.

New some scripts not work because of the fact that css is not loading at all.

I tried 5 different approach but all fail.

1. In header.php I just give them like `<style> </style>`
2. I used register style in functions.php, header.php and footer.php

```
    function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
 
 
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/tooplate-infinite-loop.css' );
   
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

3. I try using them by put them on header.php

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/tooplate-infinite-loop.css" />
```

4 and 5) are very similar I used costume style in element or, theme builder etc.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds strange if you have tried all these methods correctly and properly.
I think you have to check these points:

- Purge cache in the whole website if you use a plugin for that
- Check your css file name if is written correctly, and is the correct path

To solve this problem definitely and quickly, i recommend you to use a child theme generator plugin, to achieve this task. One of the best option is a plugin called *Child Theme Configurator* which you can find at [Child Theme Configurator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/)

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thank for helping. It was was plugging conflict. There was installed Master Addons Pro which used bootstrap in differ version then my theme, and override my settings, thus not working many of CSS or JS. Anyone know any way to avoid situation like this? For instance, to say my own-created plugin when CSS from another themes or plugin involve on it, to do not use it on itself?

Comment: @kamildanilski you posted that as a solution to your question, if you want to reply to Anass you should do it as a comment. Remember this is not a discussion forum it's a Question Answer site, the format isn't the same. I've converted your answer into a comment reply, be careful as people will think you've solved your question if you post an answer

Comment: Kamil, to answer your second question, the best way to avoid this problem is to not use too many plugins that attempt to do too much.  The best plugins all perform a specific function and don't add a bunch of stuff that will create conflicts.  I have never heard of Master Addons Pro, but considering how many themes use Bootstrap it seems like a bad idea that the plugin developer would include a conflict.  At the very least they should include an option to disable their own inclusion of things.